# Do Duels Count Toward Total Dominance

Tags: hearthstone

The Hearthstone "Total Dominance" quest is: "Win 7 games in any mode"

Does "any mode" include duels?

I know that quest has been around longer than the actual ability to duel has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every mode including duels and single-player mode (versus the innkeeper on normal/hard as well as Nax) will count toward the quest "Total Dominance", so long as you win the match. Even dueling a buddy that then concedes seven times in a row will be enough to net you your 100 gold.